# gp-pages not able to update existing branch

Tags: github, github-pages, gatsby

I am using the following to publish by site to github pages

```
"deploy": "gatsby build --prefix-paths && gh-pages -d public -b gh-pages"
```

It works only for the first time. After the site get published on github and later when I try to  update content and run the deploy script again I get error:

```
fatal: A branch named 'gh-pages' already exists.
```

Same issue when using the master branch as well

To resolve the above issue I removed ~node_modules/gh-pages/.cache

After removing I get another set of errors:

```
fatal: attempt to fetch/clone from a shallow repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages#when-get-error-branch-already-exists

Comment: Now I get:
fatal: attempt to fetch/clone from a shallow repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

if you installed this `gh-pages` localy then you must delete this directory :
`node_modules/.cache/gh-pages`

#### if its gllobaly it will be in this path:

windos path will be : `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gh-pages\.cache\<GITREPO>`